# Replace spaces with &nbsp; between PRE tags

Tags: php, regex

I need to extend the functionality of the following code snippet to convert spaces -only- between PRE tags in a string containing html:

```
str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',$str);
```

For example, if $str cotained the following string;

```
<p>abc 123</p>
<pre class="abc" id="123">abcedfg 12345</pre>
```

it would be converted to:

```
<p>abc 123</p>
<pre class="abc" id="123">abcedfg&nbsp;12345</pre>
```

similarly;

```
<p>abc 123</p>
<pre>abcedfg 12345</pre>
```

would be converted to:

```
<p>abc 123</p>
<pre>abcedfg&nbsp;12345</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = '<pre>test 1234 123</pre>';
$text2 = '<pre class="test">test 1234 123</pre>';

function testreplace($text) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/[\<]pre(.*)[\>](.*)[\<]\/pre[\>]/i', 
        create_function(
            '$matches',
            'return "<pre".$matches[1].">".str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $matches[2])."</pre>\n";'
        ), $text);
}

echo testreplace($text);
echo testreplace($text2);
```

Took me a while... But it works.

Comment: @henasraf: please paste your code without escaping html special characters. Then select your code and use the code format button `{ }` in the editor.

Comment: @SalmanA Ah I see :P yeah that gave me some problems to paste around here haha
@Graham yep

Answer (score 2):

You can use a DOM parser. Here is how you would do it using PHP native DOM functions:

```
<?php
$test = '
<p>abc 123</p>
<pre class="abc" id="pre123">abcedfg 12345</pre>
<p>abc 123</p>
<pre class="abc" id="pre456">abcedfg 12345</pre>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <pre class="abc" id="pre789">abcedfg 12345</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
';
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$dom->loadHTML($test);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$pre = $xpath->query("//pre");
foreach($pre as $e) {
    $e->nodeValue = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $e->nodeValue);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

## Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>abc 123</p>
<pre class="abc" id="pre123">abcedfg&nbsp;12345</pre>
<p>abc 123</p>
<pre class="abc" id="pre456">abcedfg&nbsp;12345</pre>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <pre class="abc" id="pre789">abcedfg&nbsp;12345</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></body></html>
```

## EDIT:

I am not sure how to get rid of doctype/html/body tags. One possible solution that works on PHP >= 5.3.6 is to specify which node to output in the [`saveHTML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) method. Other possibility is to use regex which I have avoided in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Salman. I will restructure my question based on your answer.

Comment: Righto, I have raised a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716486/convert-spaces-between-pre-tags-via-dom-parser

Please feel free to continue the DOM parser solution there, I am not sure how to remove the doctype/html/body tags either.. I do have PHP >= 5.3.6

Comment: It's "cleaner" than RegEx on the eyes, but other than that it seems unnecessary to start messing with DOM for one relatively simple action

Comment: @graham: I noticed the shortcomings in my answer, I've therefore posted updated answer on your other question.