# How replace all spaces inside HTML PRE elements with &nbsp;

Tags: php, regex

Similar to [How replace all spaces inside HTML elements with &nbsp; using preg_replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210287/how-replace-all-spaces-inside-html-elements-with-nbsp-using-preg-replace)

Except I only want to modify spaces found between PRE tags. For example:

```
<table atrr="zxzx"><tr>
<td>adfa a   adfadfaf></td><td><br /> dfa  dfa</td>
</tr></table>
<pre class="abc" id="abc">abc abc</pre>
<pre>123 123</pre>
```

would be converted to (note the pre tag may contain attributes, or may not):

```
<table atrr="zxzx"><tr>
<td>adfa a   adfadfaf></td><td><br /> dfa  dfa</td>
</tr></table>
<pre class="abc" id="abc">abc&nbsp;abc</pre>
<pre>123&nbsp;123</pre>
```

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715922/replace-spaces-with-nbsp-between-pre-tags/6716111#6716111

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$html = preg_replace(
      '#(\<pre[^>]*>)(.*)(</pre>)#Umie'
    , "'$1'.str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', '$2').'$3'"
    , $html);
```

Has been tested, works with the sample string you provided. It's ungreedy, you don't want to replace spaces between `</pre>` and `<pre>`. Also works if the `<pre></pre>` section spans several lines.

Note: this will fail if you have nested situations like `<pre> <pre> </pre> </pre>`. If you want to be able to parse that, you need to parse the (X)HTML using the [Document Object Model](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Update:
I have done some benchmarking and it turns out the callback version is faster by about 1 second per 100,000 iterations, so I think I should also mention that option.

```
$html = preg_replace_callback(
      '#(\<pre[^>]*>)(.*)(</pre>)#Uim'
    , function($matches){
          return $matches[1].str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $matches[2]).$matches[3];
      }
    , $html);
```

This requires PHP 5.3 or newer, earlier versions do not support anonymous functions.

Comment: You can put a function in the replacement string?? Where in the documentation does it say that?

Comment: That's because of the `e` modifier of the regex. It means that the result string will be eval'd, so as long as you make sure it produces correct PHP code you can also include function calls. An alternative solution would be to use `preg_replace_callback` and specify a callback function.

Comment: You need to add the `'s'` _single-line/dot-matches-all_ modifier to get the dot-star to span lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
do
     $html = preg_replace('/(<pre.*>.*) (.*<\/pre>)/', '$1&nbsp;$2', $html, 1, $count);
while($count);

echo $html;
```

I'm not sure if there's a better solution. I'm not very familiar with all the preg functions.

Comment: the `.*` inside `<pre.*>` is greedy. it'll consume too much if you have 2 `<pre>` tags.

Comment: @Mark There's nothing wrong with it being greedy in this case since I put it in a loop it will still work correctly. It's just not a nice a solution as Arjan's

Comment: http://ideone.com/I11cT Hrm....now I'm really confused. I thought the first iteration would replace the very last space... why isn't it doing that? (It still loops one more time than it needs to....and it shouldn't need to loop at all though)

Comment: Ahhh... nevermind. Forgot the "dot matches all" modifier...that's what was confusing me! http://ideone.com/OyS9a This does what I was expecting. You'll see it also converts the space between the span. That's why greedy is bad!