# PHP XML DOM unwanted escaping characters, i cannot write &qnot;

Tags: php, xml, dom, escaping, special-characters

i'm having a problem with

```
$xml2 = new DOMDocument;
$xml2->load($FilenamePost."/".$FilenameOfThePost.'.xml');

/* filename.xml */
$xpath2 = new DOMXPath($xml2);
$hrefs2 = $xpath2->evaluate("/page");

$Title = str_replace("-==single-quote==--"," &quot; ",$Title);
$Title = str_replace('-==double-quote==--',' &quot; ',$Title);

$Title = str_replace('&amp;quot;',' &quot; ',$Title);

$Title = "Sssa &quot;";

$href2 = $hrefs2->item(0);
$href2->setAttribute("PostTitle",$Title);

$xml2->save($FilenamePost."/".$FilenameOfThePost.'.xml');

/*
And when i try to write 
&quot; 
in my xml, it keeps showing 
&amp;quot;
*/
```

WHY IS THIS??? I cannot find a logical explication ...

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716486/convert-spaces-between-pre-tags-via-dom-parser/6716538#6716538

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do that:

```
$Title = str_replace("-==single-quote==--", ' " ',$Title);
$Title = str_replace('-==double-quote==--', ' " ',$Title);
```

And you will have your `&quot;` in xml.

Comment: this actually works, but, oh boy, they have encoding by default?? LOL!

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `"` directly, DomDocument takes care of escaping it.

```
$Title = "Sssa &";
...
...->setAttribute("PostTitle", $Title);
```

When saving, the PostTitle attribute will be properly escaped:

```
<... PostTitle="Sssa &quot;" ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

setAttribute() does escaping by default so you might need to use html_entity_decode() if the string is already escaped:

```
$href2->setAttribute("PostTitle", html_entity_decode($Title));
```

Comment: No solution is working correctly. Facing entity related problem.